# ThinkPad P50 & Ubuntu 22.04: cannot wake up at all, why?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, suspend, thinkpad

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on the ThinkPad P50 and cannot wake up the machine after suspend any more. Just after installation there was some offering for the firmware update that I did, but now pressing the power button when it slowly flashes after going to sleep doesn't work. The only thing I can do is to press it over five seconds to turn the computer off.

The funny part I've noticed yesterday is that as I set up `systemd` to use `sleep-then-hibernate`, turning it off (5 sec pressing power) then turning it on actually in one case restored it from hibernation. So the part I wanted to get to work to save battery when I put the computer away for longer seem to do the job, but I can't wake it up from the original suspension, for example after closing the lid.

I can't find any BIOS obvious options who would infer with the behaviour on this model.

Any advice very welcome.

Comment: Hi I experienced the same issue with my Thinkpad T460s. The laptop gets hot in hiberation mode or when plugged in for charging and unused for a while. The only way I could get back was by pressing the reset hole on the buttom of the case. I switched back to Arch and have no issue in leaving the pc unused and charging.

Comment: I have Lenovo T460. Same thing. I test booting from the installer and then choose Power Off. It didn't turn off the computer. For the time being I guess I have to use workaround by using hibernating.

Comment: I have the same issue with a X1 carbon. Can you explain in more detail what is the hibernate workaround?

Comment: same issue on ThinkPad E480

Comment: @LEo on Ubuntu 22.04? I'm stating to think it's something they did to the kernel.

Comment: @MichałF Yes. But using Awesome WM there is no problem (at least so far) in the suspend and come back.

Comment: @LEo I tried Awesome and did not fix the problem on my X1 carbon 4th gen.

Comment: I should launch earlier version live distro from USB and check the sleeping, but I don't have time ATM and USBs are scarce at my premises.

Comment: Considering that downgrading to Linux 5.8 fixed my issues previously, I suspect that it is the kernel

Comment: Aleksandr Panzin You've did that on 22.04? May I ask how?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @aleksandr-panzin comment I found the answer and good enough solution. You can skip to Guide to avoid long version.

The answer first:

My problems started just after installing 22.04, then still in beta. I thought problems are related to firmware updates that followed... so I wasted significant amount of time around that problem.

But then Aleksandr suggested couple days ago installation of Kernel 5.8 fixes his problems with suspend. I started to figure out how to repeat that experiment. My attempt to use 5.8.18 failed as it couldn't find the root filesystem, so I've attacked from the most recent angle... and  the Kernel 5.18.3 loaded nicely.

### Hypothesis

The 5.15.0 Kernel in 22.04 is broken for quite large number of Lenovo machines.

### Test 1: Suspend

So, after it loaded I selected *Power Off/Log Out > Suspend* from the top right menu. Thrilling moment. The green LED on the Power Button started to to flash slowly... at that point since 22.04 I could only press it long to shut down the machine and start again.

So I pressed it shortly.

And computer waked up!

### Test 2: Hibernation

As Gnome doesn't offer hibernation button by default, I've fired `sudo systemctl hibernate` and let the machine dump the content of memory and shut itself down.

It nicely finished the hibernation and powered off.

Pressing the power button shortly turned it on.

After a few seconds I was on the login screen.

### Theory

So, now the hypothesis turned into a theory - the Kernel matters.

### Guide

Follow these steps to help yourself:

1. Disable Secure Boot in your BIOS/EFI settings (that part you have to figure out by yourself)
2. [Install `mainline`](https://davejansen.com/install-a-linux-kernel-of-choice-under-ubuntu/):

   ```bash
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
   sudo apt install mainline
   ```
3. Either launch via GUI and select the kernel 5.18.3 (or other if you wish), then click *Install*,

   or

   Execute the following command:

   ```bash
   mainline --install 5.18.3
   ```

### Report

Please report in comments to this answer if the above solution helped you and the model of your machine (it would be nice if you provide exact Lenovo model ID like 20EQ-S0RK1X). I could file a bug report pointing at collection of cases here (by comments and up-votes, at least 7 including me).

**Thank you.**

Comment: The solution worked on my Lenovo ThinkPad T460s, thanks!

Comment: I upgraded to 5.18.17 first, to no avail. And then to 5.19.2. Not helpfull either. Model Lenovo P50 20ENCTO1WW. Quite a serious issue to still appear in a .1 version of an LTS release. I deliberately waited for the .1 version and Lenovo laptops are far from rare.

Comment: The only version that works for me is 5.18.3, later don't.

Comment: 5.19.5 fixed it for me - thinkpad t460p thanks!

Comment: I tried Kernel 5.18.3 on my Lenovo P50 and it didn't work. Now I'm back on Kernel 6.2.0-39-generic and still having this super annoying bug! Always have to shut down the computer instead leaving it in hibernation to continue working next day.... what a shame -.- Are there some other resources how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like not all P50s are equal. Do you have all firmware updates installed?